Can a shortcut know which automation triggered it?
I have created a shortcut that logs the current location, and set up automations on my iPhone that trigger this shortcut when I arrive at and leave from certain locations. This works fine, except that it does not log whether I was arriving or leaving. Can the shortcut, running on the iPhone, somehow find out which automation triggered it, so that this information can be included in the log?
(Obviously, I can create separate "log arrival" and "log departure" shortcuts. I’m just curious whether there is a more "parametrized" solution.)
